# Comments with nested replies

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database looks like:

```
id
reply_to
text
```

Data like:

```
id          1           2           3       4       5
reply_to    NULL        1           1       2       1
text        WOW         MUCH WOW    WHAT?   0_0     ?
```

Where is `NULL` - top level comment.

I want to get something like:

```
#1 WOW
    #2 MUCH WOW
        #4 WHAT?
    #3 0_0
    #5 ?
...
```

So, query should return data in that order: `1, 2, 4, 3, 5`

So, is it possible to select already sorted comments from database or I should sort them after query?

**UPDATE:**
I forgot that it's important to get user nickname from another database.
So, database:

```
id
reply_to
text
topic_id
user_id
```

All works fine with `topic_id = 1` in `WHERE`, but what about user_nickname from another table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple case of a recursive query:

```
with recursive replies as (
   select id, reply_to, text, 0 as level, array[id] as sort_path
   from threads --<< replace with your real table name
   where reply_to is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.reply_to, c.text, p.level + 1, p.sort_path||c.id
   from threads c
     join replies p on p.id = c.reply_to
)
select rpad(' ', level * 2)||'#'||id||' '||text
from replies
order by sort_path
```

The `with` part is called a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and recursively retrieves all replies.

The outer select then simply formats the display and indents the lines.

The `sort_path` column is used to properly sort the final result.

If you *only* want the IDs returned in the correct order, simply use:

```
with recursive replies as (
   select id, array[id] as sort_path
   from threads 
   where reply_to is null
   union all
   select c.id, p.sort_path||c.id
   from threads c
     join replies p on p.id = c.reply_to
)
select id
from replies
order by sort_path
```

in the final select statement. To understand what the array is for, you might want to display it as well in your query tool then this becomes obvious.

Comment: You understood me just a bit wrong. I want to get comments in wanted order, not in that view. But I think I understand how to do this.

Comment: @ShamilYakupov: if you only want the IDs in the correct order, then only select that column in the outer query.